# C# Custom display formatting for String fields

Tags: c#, string-formatting, numeric

I would like to be able to apply the following display masks in c# to doubles to produce formatted strings.

For example I want the following display masks:

- 0;(0) to produce a format like 126524
- 0,.00;(0,.00) gives 183.94
- Total Spend: €0,.00;(0,.00) -> "Total Spend €12.34"
- 0 Days -> "0 Days"

The display masks are input by a user so can be wide in nature. They can also contain text. I have been able to do similar using a DevExpress AspxGridView, a column has a DisplayFormatString that I can use.

e.g. I have a variable named FormatString (e.g. "Total Spend: €0,.00;(0,.00)") which a user enters, I can assign to a grid column like:

```
       columnDisplayFormatString = FormatString
```

I need to do something similar in a Web Service so can't use any third party UI components.

I know I can always parse the format string and derive the parameters needed for String.Format but this could get quite messy.

Answer (score 2):

There's alot of information available here about string formats:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: I'm aware of string formats. What I need here is a mechanism to apply a format entered by a user that can contain text to a value. It may be a case that I have to parse the input string and apply the formats like you have linked to.